# C - Two types of formatted user input with an unknown number of inputs

Tags: c, input, io

I want the user to be able to input two types of input like: "C[some size_t]" and "O[some memory address]" and depending on whether it's a C or O at the beginning, I'll call different functions. I also want to be able to take in an unknown number of those inputs and in any order.

My way of going around it was something like this:

```
int main()
{
    // variables

    while (1) { // Infinite loop to take in multiple unknown amount of inputs?
        while (fgets(input, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)) {
            if (sscanf(input, "%c%zu", &branch, &num) == 2) {
                if (strcmp(&branch, "C")
                    // function call
            } else if (sscanf(input, "%c%c", &branch, (char *)addr) == 2) {
                if (strcmp(&branch, "O")
                    // function call
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand why it's not working of course and I know my not-solution is wrong but I have no idea how else to go about this. The code takes in the first input and just hangs and if I start with an input beginning with O, it'll go into the first `if` statement when it's not supposed to. I'm also not sure if my `while(1)` loop is the correct way to deal with multiple user inputs.

Comment: Be careful: All strings functions (like `strcmp`) expects their arguments to be proper null-terminated strings. You can't treat single characters like strings. If you want to compare characters use normal comparisons like `==`. As in `if (branch == 'C')`

Comment: And while it's not applicable in your case (since it's wrong to begin with) remember that `strcmp` returns **`0`** if the two strings are equal. And that `0` is considered *false*.

Comment: I also suggest you add some kind of *prompt* so the users will know that the program is ready to read input.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh! Thank you, I forgot about that. I'm still in the Java mindset when comparing strings haha

Comment: Why would you scan twice into `branch`? Wouldn't you scan just once and then check? `if(scanf(branch) == numberOfScannedValues) { if(branch == ...) {} else if(branch == ...) {} } else { /* handle invalid input */ }` – and you'd have to scan the second argument separately inside the respective `if`s.

Comment: @Aconcagua That's how I first approached the problem but then I didn't know how I'd read the following values? It's definitely me being dumb but I can't think of a valid way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to read the `branch` char and the respective argument in one single go – however the argument differs in both cases. So you need first to read the character, then decide and only *then* scan the argument – as soon as you know what to scan at all and thus are able to select the appropriate format string.

As you just read in *any* character you could do so a bit simpler with `getc`, by the way:

```
char branch = getc(); // instead of `if(scanf("%c", &branch) == 1)`
                      // note: would have been one single scan (branch) only!
if(branch == 'C')
{
    // scan num
}
else if(branch == 'O')
{
    // scan addr
}
else
{
    // error handling
}
```

or alternatively (I personally would prefer)

```
char branch = getc();
switch(branch)
{
case 'C':
    // scan num
    break;
case 'O':
    // scan addr
    break;
default:
    // error handling
    break;
}
```

Note that `strcmp` requires null-terminated strings (char arrays) and cannot be used for comparing single characters – these need to be compared via equality operator, see above.

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful but how would I scan the rest of the argument? The first letter and the second part isn't separated by a space or anything. I tried putting an `if(scanf("%c%zu", &branch, &num) == 2)` in each case but when I try to print the value of num, for example, it doesn't read the first integer. E.g. If user inputs "C124", num is set to 24. I'm guessing this has something to do with the null terminator?

Comment: @bachtick No, not at all. Remember that with `getc` you've *already read* the `C` character, so all that's remaining is `124`. If you now scan for `"%c%zu"` you are reading `'1'` as character into `branch`, leaving `24` for num. So once you already got `C` you *only* scan for the number: `if(scanf("%zu", &num) == 1) { ... }`, analogously for `addr`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense ! Silly me. Thank you so much